# 13.10 network Epson printer stuck on "Installing"

Tags: drivers, 13.10, printing

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10, and I can't configure my wi-fi `Epson TX430W` printer.

Using the `Settings->Printers` interface, I can detect the printer. When I click add, I briefly see a "Searching for drivers" dialog. It dissapears, and then I'm left with the printer forever in "Installing" status.

If I close the window and reopen `Printers`, it doesn't show up on the list.

How can I solve, or at least diagnose the problem?

Comment: I can't find any information on a TX430W... When and where did you get it?

Comment: Ah, I found it. It appears to only be sold in Latin America. Epson itself doesn't have an Linux drivers for this particular printer.

Comment: @Seth thanks, yes, I live in latam. I'm now trying to manually install the generic drivers, without the graphical interface. If this fails, I'll update the post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I opened a terminal and launched `system-config-printer`, the old configuration interface. I followed the steps until I was presented with 3 driver options for the printer.

`system-config-printer` dumps data about these drivers to the terminal, in particular the URL for the `deb` file served by Epson. I manually downloaded and installed the driver.

With the driver pre-installed, the normal configuration process worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the network printer on 13.11 GUI (fresh install) was stuck regardless if I selected the "download driver" (gutenprint) or not. I did sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint, but it didn't help. A temporary fix: starting

> system-config-printer

in the terminal and pressing Ctrl+C when the dialog freezes I was able to get through to the next dialog step, where I could see the manual selection list. The recommended setting (generic printer driver) worked fine.

Those problems were not present in the version 10.04.

Comment: Mine was just a case of 3rd time lucky. I had to kill the installer the first time, the second time I was asked if I wanted to use gutenprint and it proceeded to do nothing, then finally I selectef gutenprint and it Just Worked™

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround on 15.10: install the driver manually first**

```
# Clean up messy state we were left in.
sudo killall -9 system-config-printer.py
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat

# Search for the driver
apt-cache search epson-inkjet-printer | less
```

The packet description contains the model name. E.g., I have an XP-202, so my package is:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201202w - Epson XP-30/102/202/205 Series - Epson Inkjet Printer Driver
```

The `201202w` also shows on the GUI when you get to choose which driver to install.

Now just:

```
sudo apt-get install epson-inkjet-printer-201202w
system-config-printer
```

And add the printer normally.

**Launchpad bug report**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1307917

Comment: Thanks! I opened system-config-printer to see the driver name, instead of using `apt-cache search`, then manually installed it according to your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are getting this issue now, Seiko Epson Corp. has provided a free software (GPL license) printer driver package for Linux that supports a large number of Epson printers.  It looks like it supports the TX430 series as well.  (https://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-escpr)

It's available to Ubuntu as printer-driver-escpr.

Step 1: Clean up files so that we can install printer drivers without errors regarding debconf/config.dat being locked. (Thanks Ciro!)
`$ sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*dat`

Step 2: Install printer-driver-escpr.
`$ sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr`

Step 3: Start up your printer utility and select your printer.

Step 4: Choose to install a "Local Driver", select the model closest to your printer, and continue.

You should now be able to use your printer.  Verified on LXLE 14.04, derived from Lubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.