# Ubuntu 14.04 will not recognise my Epson WP4545 printer.

Tags: wireless, drivers, epson

Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognise my Epson WP4545 wireless printer. When Add printer, it finds it, and the proper driver, but when I try to download the driver it freezes. I have un-installed Ubuntu and re-installed, with the same result. I have been at this for weeks and getting no where.

Comment: What that this file? http://ubuntuone.com/5KBwwCA4TC3n6UkHgaW0ft

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/415099/13-10-network-epson-printer-stuck-on-installing http://askubuntu.com/questions/461506/driver-installation-stuck. Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1307917

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install this file [`epson-inkjet-printer-201113w_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb`](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=19445&DSCCHK=f19be7033a2aa451249ee62d3c088d4cb5985f47)
- Then go back to 'My printer' and press 'Find printer' then it will get installed.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it will not install, freezes half way through, same as other attempts at installing other drivers. Should Ubuntu not recognise the Epson printers automatically. as some claims say?

Answer (score 0):

For people who are getting this issue now, the general solution is to download the driver manually, and select the Local Driver option to use it instead of getting into the infinite loop issue.  Ubuntu has the printer-driver-escpr package, which supports a large number of Epson printers.

Step 1: Kill the printer utility if it's frozen.  (Skip this step if you haven't opened the printer utility yet.)

Step 2: Clean up files so that we can install printer drivers without errors regarding debconf/config.dat being locked.
`$ sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*dat`

Step 3: Install printer-driver-escpr.
`$ sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr`

Step 4: Start up your printer utility and select your printer.

Step 5: Choose to install a "Local Driver", select the model closest to your printer, and continue.

You should now be able to use your printer.  Verified on LXLE 14.04, derived from Lubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.